# C# UWP Bitmap - how to programatically create an indexed bitmap?

Tags: c#, bitmap, uwp

I am currently writing an app which will programatically convert a given image to an 8-bit bitmap for use with the [XDC 8086 video/animation system](https://x86dc.wordpress.com/). I already know how to do the conversion using the .NET Framework:

```
public Bitmap Dither(Bitmap source)
{
    Bitmap target = new Bitmap(source.Width,source.Height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    //...call conversion/dithering code and methods here
    return target;
}
```

However, I have been unsuccessful in finding, through reading the UWP documentation and doing research here as well as on Google, a similar or equivalent means of doing so in UWP. Am I missing something?

Comment: UWP does not have access to `System.Drawing` (GDI).

Comment: Windows Imaging Component (WIC) replaces GDI for image loading/saving and is exposed to UWP via `BitmapEncoder` and `BitmapDecoder` - it's not exactly what you're looking for but seems a good place to start looking from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709936.aspx